# Star Markers - unable to get tie points in Inpho Match-AT

Tags: photogrammetry, aerial-triangulation, inpho-match-at

What do the star markers mean in Trimble's Inpho Match-AT software, specifically in the multi-photo measurement feature?

I have been unable to generate tie points in an aerial triangulation in photos which have no star in the center icon.

[image]

I don't know what they mean or why they don't have stars. The photos are present and connected, they have initialized external orientations and correct camera parameters, and each file does actually have data.

I haven't been able to find anything in any help documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the past two months since I asked this question, I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. I have come to the conclusion that the star markers indicated photocenters that contain generated tie points, and even when those tie points are deleted the attribution remains.